# What's wrong with my auto layout constraints?

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint

Here is my UIViewController before I press a button (I didn't put it there as it is not relevant):

[image]

When I press the button, a UIView containing two UIPickerView appear from the top. Right under this UIView are 2 UIButtons. Everthing works with auto layout:

[image]

Here is the code when I create the constraints:

```
let okButtonHeight: CGFloat = 53
let okButtonWidth: CGFloat = 53
let leftPickerViewWidth: CGFloat = 80
let leftPickerViewHeight: CGFloat = 200
let margin: CGFloat = 8

// frame
let constraint0 = NSLayoutConstraint(item: okButton, attribute: .Bottom, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: .Top, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
let constraint1 = NSLayoutConstraint(item: frameView, attribute: .CenterX, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: view, attribute: .CenterX, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)

// left & right pickerViews
let constraint2 = NSLayoutConstraint(item: leftPickerView, attribute: .Width, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: rightPickerView, attribute: .Width, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
let constraint3 = NSLayoutConstraint(item: leftPickerView, attribute: .Height, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: rightPickerView, attribute: .Height, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
let constraint4 = NSLayoutConstraint(item: leftPickerView, attribute: .Trailing, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: rightPickerView, attribute: .Leading, multiplier: 1, constant: -margin)
let constraint5 = NSLayoutConstraint(item: leftPickerView, attribute: .Top, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: rightPickerView, attribute: .Top, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)

// left pickerView
let constraint6 = NSLayoutConstraint(item: leftPickerView, attribute: .Height, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .NotAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: leftPickerViewHeight)
let constraint7 = NSLayoutConstraint(item: leftPickerView, attribute: .Width, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .NotAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: leftPickerViewWidth)
let constraint8 = NSLayoutConstraint(item: leftPickerView, attribute: .Top, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: frameView, attribute: .Top, multiplier: 1, constant: -margin)
let constraint9 = NSLayoutConstraint(item: leftPickerView, attribute: .Bottom, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: frameView, attribute: .Bottom, multiplier: 1, constant: margin)
let constraint10 = NSLayoutConstraint(item: leftPickerView, attribute: .Leading, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: frameView, attribute: .Leading, multiplier: 1, constant: margin)

// right pickerView
let constraint11 = NSLayoutConstraint(item: rightPickerView, attribute: .Trailing, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: frameView, attribute: .Trailing, multiplier: 1, constant: -margin)

// ok & cancel buttons
let constraint12 = NSLayoutConstraint(item: okButton, attribute: .Top, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: cancelButton, attribute: .Top, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
let constraint13 = NSLayoutConstraint(item: okButton, attribute: .Bottom, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: cancelButton, attribute: .Bottom, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
let constraint14 = NSLayoutConstraint(item: okButton, attribute: .Width, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: cancelButton, attribute: .Width, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
let constraint15 = NSLayoutConstraint(item: okButton, attribute: .Height, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: cancelButton, attribute: .Height, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)

// ok button
let constraint16 = NSLayoutConstraint(item: view, attribute: .CenterX, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: okButton, attribute: .Trailing, multiplier: 1, constant: 10)
let constraint17 = NSLayoutConstraint(item: okButton, attribute: .Width, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .NotAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: okButtonWidth)
let constraint18 = NSLayoutConstraint(item: okButton, attribute: .Height, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .NotAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: okButtonHeight)
let constraint19 = NSLayoutConstraint(item: okButton, attribute: .Top, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: frameView, attribute: .Bottom, multiplier: 1, constant: 10)

// cancel button
let constraint20 = NSLayoutConstraint(item: view, attribute: .CenterX, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: cancelButton, attribute: .Leading, multiplier: 1, constant: -10)

view.addConstraint(constraint0)
view.addConstraint(constraint1)
view.addConstraint(constraint12)
view.addConstraint(constraint13)
view.addConstraint(constraint14)
view.addConstraint(constraint15)
view.addConstraint(constraint16)
view.addConstraint(constraint17)
view.addConstraint(constraint18)
view.addConstraint(constraint19)
view.addConstraint(constraint20)

frameView.addConstraint(constraint2)
frameView.addConstraint(constraint3)
frameView.addConstraint(constraint4)
frameView.addConstraint(constraint5)
frameView.addConstraint(constraint6)
frameView.addConstraint(constraint7)
frameView.addConstraint(constraint8)
frameView.addConstraint(constraint9)
frameView.addConstraint(constraint10)
frameView.addConstraint(constraint11)

selectionCurrencyConstraintList = [constraint0, constraint1, constraint2, constraint3, constraint4, constraint5, constraint6, constraint7, constraint8, constraint9, constraint10, constraint11, constraint12, constraint13, constraint14, constraint15, constraint16, constraint17, constraint18, constraint19, constraint20]

frameView.hidden = true
okButton.hidden = true
cancelButton.hidden = true
```

At that point, the UIView and the two buttons are hidden just above the top of the screen.

When I press the button to make it appear, I execute this code:

```
frameView.hidden = hide
okButton.hidden = hide
cancelButton.hidden = hide

if var constraints = selectionCurrencyConstraintList {
    let topFrameConstraint = constraints[0]
    view.removeConstraint(topFrameConstraint)
    constraints.removeAtIndex(0)
    let newTopConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
    if hide {
        newTopConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: okButton, attribute: .Bottom, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: .Top, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
    } else {
        newTopConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: frameView, attribute: .Top, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: topView, attribute: .Bottom, multiplier: 1, constant: margin)
    }
    constraints.insert(newTopConstraint, atIndex: 0)
    view.addConstraint(newTopConstraint)
}

UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5) {
    self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
}
```

When I replace this constraint `NSLayoutConstraint(item: okButton, attribute: .Bottom, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: .Top, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)` by this one `NSLayoutConstraint(item: frameView, attribute: .Top, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: topView, attribute: .Bottom, multiplier: 1, constant: margin)` it works fine.

When I reverse it, I got some constraints that cannot be satisfied:

```
2015-05-15 20:17:25.374 CurrencyEx[624:42779] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. Try this: (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) 
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x17408de30 V:[UIView:0x174186660(50)]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x174090fe0 V:[_UILayoutGuide:0x1741a8a40]-(0)-[UIView:0x174186660]>",
    "<_UILayoutSupportConstraint:0x1740a3e40 V:[_UILayoutGuide:0x1741a8a40(20)]>",
    "<_UILayoutSupportConstraint:0x1740a3d80 V:|-(0)-[_UILayoutGuide:0x1741a8a40]   (Names: '|':UIView:0x174186590 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x170089150 V:[UIButton:0x146e49020(53)]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x1700891a0 V:[UIView:0x1741868d0]-(10)-[UIButton:0x146e49020]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x170088d90 V:[UIPickerView:0x146e09ef0(200)]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x170088e30 V:|-(-8)-[UIPickerView:0x146e09ef0]   (Names: '|':UIView:0x1741868d0 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x170088e80 UIPickerView:0x146e09ef0.bottom == UIView:0x1741868d0.bottom + 8>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x17008ef60 V:[UIView:0x174186660]-(8)-[UIView:0x1741868d0]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x174096620 UIButton:0x146e49020.bottom == UIView:0x174186590.top>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x170088e80 UIPickerView:0x146e09ef0.bottom == UIView:0x1741868d0.bottom + 8>

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKit/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
2015-05-15 20:17:25.377 CurrencyEx[624:42779] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. Try this: (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) 
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x17408de30 V:[UIView:0x174186660(50)]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x174090fe0 V:[_UILayoutGuide:0x1741a8a40]-(0)-[UIView:0x174186660]>",
    "<_UILayoutSupportConstraint:0x1740a3e40 V:[_UILayoutGuide:0x1741a8a40(20)]>",
    "<_UILayoutSupportConstraint:0x1740a3d80 V:|-(0)-[_UILayoutGuide:0x1741a8a40]   (Names: '|':UIView:0x174186590 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x170089150 V:[UIButton:0x146e49020(53)]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x1700891a0 V:[UIView:0x1741868d0]-(10)-[UIButton:0x146e49020]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x17008ef60 V:[UIView:0x174186660]-(8)-[UIView:0x1741868d0]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x174096620 UIButton:0x146e49020.bottom == UIView:0x174186590.top>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x17408de30 V:[UIView:0x174186660(50)]>

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKit/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
2015-05-15 20:17:25.378 CurrencyEx[624:42779] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. Try this: (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) 
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x174090fe0 V:[_UILayoutGuide:0x1741a8a40]-(0)-[UIView:0x174186660]>",
    "<_UILayoutSupportConstraint:0x1740a3e40 V:[_UILayoutGuide:0x1741a8a40(20)]>",
    "<_UILayoutSupportConstraint:0x1740a3d80 V:|-(0)-[_UILayoutGuide:0x1741a8a40]   (Names: '|':UIView:0x174186590 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x170089150 V:[UIButton:0x146e49020(53)]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x1700891a0 V:[UIView:0x1741868d0]-(10)-[UIButton:0x146e49020]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x17008ef60 V:[UIView:0x174186660]-(8)-[UIView:0x1741868d0]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x174096620 UIButton:0x146e49020.bottom == UIView:0x174186590.top>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x1700891a0 V:[UIView:0x1741868d0]-(10)-[UIButton:0x146e49020]>
```

I don't understand why. It works at first with those constraints. When I modify some of them it works, and when I put them back, it doesn't work anymore...

Any idea?

Comment: Try using constraints from storyboard or nib rather then code then you will find better solutions in there. Using code for auto layout is bad practice

Comment: Try to set all your constraints in storyboard, then before each of your animations set `setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(_:)` to YES

Comment: Why should I set it to YES? It won't work with auto layout then

Comment: You will not need to reset constants for all your constraints.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's call your constraints:

`ConstraintHide`: `okButton` bottom aligned with superview top.
`ConstraintShow`: `frameView` is 8 points under `topView`.

If you inspect the colliding constraints in the log one by one, you notice that both of your constraints `ConstraintHide` and `ConstraintShow` are present in the same time.

This is caused by your removal/addition of constraints.

1. Initial state

Only `ConstraintHide` is in the view

2. State after showing view

`ConstraintHide` correctly removed, `ConstraintShow` added

3. State after hiding view

`ConstraintShow` not removed, `ConstraintHide` added

4. Collision

Now the question is why step 3 hasn't removed the constraint? This is because of a bug in step 2. Your `selectionCurrencyConstraintList` was not correctly updated so in step 3 you are attempting to remove the original `ConstraintHide` constraint instead of the constraint `ConstraintShow` added by step 2.

This is due to the fact that `if var constraints = selectionCurrencyConstraintList` makes a copy of the array. So you have to save the changes in the end.

**Solution**

Add

`selectionCurrencyConstraintList = constraints`

to the end of the block.

Having said that, you can drastically simplify your code by adding all of the constraints in Interface Builder, connect `ConstraintShow` and `ConstraintHide` as outlets and instead of removing/addding them, just change priority on them from `0` to `1000`.

Comment: My hero! Yes I realized if was the optional binding when you said I might actually not delete what I thought I had deleted. Thanks a lot!

Comment: By the way, how do you manage to see my constraints `ConstraintHide` and `ConstraintShow` in this log? Isn't there an easier way to display the actual name of the constraints and not just some hexadecimal code?

Comment: @Nico I just compared the constraints in the log 1 by 1 and realized what pointer means what but if you step in the debugger, you can print out the object using `po 0x1741a8a40`. Or you can print out the entire view hierarchy and then compare the pointers.

Comment: I didn't know I could directly print out the hexa code. What about the hierarchy? How do you print it out?

Comment: `po [self.view recursiveDescription]` but the new view inspector is showing the pointers too, I think.